# finding_anagrams function is not creating dictionary of anagrams

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having problems with the finding_anagrams function. I want to create a dictionary, which is holding list for all words anagrams. the sig variable is the signature of the word arrange in alphabetical order. the dictionary takes the for of 
d = {"word1": [word2, word3, word4], "word5": [word10, word9, word20], etc...}
the input file contain a word list of english language

```
def get_signature(word):
    """takes a word breaks it into a list and sort it alph, and then
    back into a word
    """
    l = word.split()
    l.sort()    
    w = ''.join(l)
    return w    


def is_anagram(sig, word):
    """takes a given number of letters and compare to another 
    word to see if they are anagrams: must be same length
    """ 
    if len(word) != len(sig): #if words not same len return False
        print "here1"
        return False
    for ch in sig:
        if ch not in word:
            return False

    return True     


def finding_anagrams(fin):
    """Ex 12-4 this funcion reads a wordlist and find the words that makes up 
    the most anagrams
    """
    #read the wordlist file 
    d = {}
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        sig = get_signature(word) #put the letters in alphabetical
        if sig not in d:
            d[sig] = []
        for l in fin:
            w = l.strip().lower()
            print w, sig, "here"
            if is_anagram(sig, w):
                d[sig].append(w)

    return d                    



def print_anagrams(number, d):
    """prints all anagrams of given word
    """
    for key, value in d.items():
        if len(key) == number:
            print key, d[key]

main()
    filein = open("words.txt")
    anagrams = finding_anagrams(filein)
    print_anagrams(5, anagrams) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import collections

def is_anagram(w1, w2):
    return collections.Counter(w1) == collections.Counter(w2)

def get_signature(word):
    return ''.join(sorted(word))

def find_anagrams(infilepath):
    answer = {}
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            word = line.strip().lower()
            sig = get_signature(word)
            if sig not in answer:
                answer[sig] = set()
            answer[sig].add(word)
    return answer

def find_most_anagrams(infilepath):
    anagrams = find_anagrams(infilepath)
    most = max(anagrams, key=lambda k:len(anagrams[k]))
    print "The maximum number of anagrams are made with the letters", most, '.'
    print "The anagrams are:",
    print '\n\t'.join(anagrams[most])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the file object twice where after the first inner loop you have exhausted the iterator. Using a defaultdict will be more efficient  and just calling sorted on the word will also avoid unnecessary function calls

```
def finding_anagrams(fin):
    """Ex 12-4 this funcion reads a wordlist and find the words that makes up
    the most anagrams
    """
    #read the wordlist file
    from collections import defaultdict
    d = defaultdict(list)
    lines = fin.readlines() # put in a list 
    for ind,line in enumerate(lines[:-1]):
        word = line.rstrip().lower()
        sig = "".join(sorted(word)) # this line does what get_signature does
        if any(is_anagram(sig, word.rstrip().lower()) for word in lines[ind+1:]): # check all words from current + 1 in the lines list 
            d[sig].append(word)
    return d
```

You can also remove the need for  is_anagram with which will in turn remove the need for sig:

```
 if any(sorted(word) == sorted(w.rstrip().lower())) for w in lines[ind+1:])
```

Comment: Excellent! I would also refine the is_anagram function is_anagram(sig, word): return sorted(sig)==sorted(word).

Comment: @user3378649, I am not fully sure what is happening in the code, I just corrected the main problem but you may well be correct

Comment: True! the over-all problem is solved. I just wanted to add a refined version of this function (which doesn't worth posting another answer).

Comment: @user3378649, I added it to the answer

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but according to your code, you'll never find all the anagrams for a given signature(key). Let's say you find a word half way down the wordlist, and you add it to the dictionary, the loop keeps going down, so you never look at the top part of the word list to check if any of those words are an anagram of the key you just added... hope it makes sence

Comment: never mind... you're always checking all anagrams for every key, since the key has already been added for those words already traversed